# Where is complex.h in spuce?

Tags: c++

I suppose I'm still new to using external libraries in C++, and I got confused by the fact that one file in the [spuce library](https://github.com/audiofilter/spuce) includes a file that I could not seem to find anywhere in the code for the GitHub repository. Specifically, one file `iir_allpass_variable_cascade.h` (found [here](https://github.com/audiofilter/spuce/blob/master/spuce/filters/iir_allpass_variable_cascade.h)) has the following line:

```
#include <spuce/complex.h>
```

This would suggest to me that the `spuce` directory should contain a file named `complex.h`, but no such file exists in this directory on GitHub. In fact, I was unable to find any file named `complex.h` in the code for this repository.

Where is the file that is actually supposed to be included by this statement?